# Element-comparison NumPy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I need a NumPy matrix with comparisons among all elements in a sequence:

```
from numpy import matrix
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3]
matrix([[cmp(a, b) for a in seq] for b in seq])
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Useful reference for anyone wanting to take this on: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `matrix` rather than `array`? I recommend sticking with `array`

As for a better way:

```
seq = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
numpy.clip(seq[:,None] - seq, -1, 1)
```

1. `seq[:, None]`, moves the numbers into the second dimension of the array
2. `seq[:, None] - seq` broadcasts the numbers against each other, and subtracts them.
3. `numpy.clip` converts lower/higher values into 1 and -1